# Custom Redirect

Tags: php, jquery, redirect, cookies

I have main folder mysite.com/ and replicated folders,such as mysite.com/10010/,mysite.com/10011/ and so on .
By  now i accomplished to delete/set cookies with Jquery Cookie plugin and redirect according to the cookies set.

To delete/set cookies I'm using following code:

```
var cookies = $.cookie();
for(var cookie in cookies) {
$.removeCookie(cookie);
}
$.cookie('10010', '10010', { expires: 30, path: '/' })
```

To redirect I'm using following code:

```
$(function() {
if ($.cookie('10010')){ window.location.href = 'http://www.mysite.com/10010';}
else if ($.cookie('10011')) {window.location.href = 'http://mysite.com/10011';}
});
```

My problem is:
For example, if a user visited a specific page, such as mysite.com/10010/page1.html,even if next time he types in browser mysite.com/page1.html he will be redirected to mywebsite.com/10010/. I need user to be redirected to mysite.com/10010/page1.html.
I have 100's of replicated folders and 100's of pages in each replicated folder - so is hard to set individual cookie for every page and redirect.

What is correct way to adjust my code? Please note that I'm new to coding. I've tried so far:

```
$(function() {
if ($.cookie('10010')){ window.location.href = 'http://www.mysite.com/10010'+ "/.html";}
else if ($.cookie('10011')) {window.location.href = 'http://mysite.com/10011'+ "/.html";}
});
```

And few different variations after "+", but none seems to be working.

Is there an easier way to do it, instead of setting cookies and redirect for EACH individual page ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are trying this, how are you detecting what page you currently on?  I'd use something like:

```
   var temp = window.location.href.split('/');
```

And one thing I notice is

```
   window.location.href = 'http://www.mysite.com/10010'+ "/.html";
```

You are using ' then you are using " which I believe is bad practice.  Also, having a space in there might screw up variable setting.  Try something like:

```
   window.location.href = 'http://www.mysite.com/10010'+'/.html';
```

Thing is when you redirect, it'd be like http://www.mysite.com/10010/.html as their redirect, unless you detect which page you are on via my .split example and do something like:

```
   window.location.href = 'http://www.mysite.com/10010/'+temp[4];
```

That's with the idea...

```
   temp[0]=http:
   temp[1]=""
   temp[2]=www.mysite.com
   temp[3]=10010
   temp[4]=page1.html
```

Comment: thanks i tried and it works..but now im redirected to http://mysite.com/10010/undefined.. im confusing where i have to add temp definitions..im new.. so please could you elaborate more..

Comment: Add this in... alert(temp.join('\n')) after you do the split, then you know what is in each array.  It's saying undefined as there is no value in temp[4], given you used my example. -- Also temp was just what I named the variable, you can name it whatever you'd like.